# Using XMLHttpRequest to get words from another website

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

As of current I am learning to use JavaScript to create web applications. I have just finished developing a hangman game (code will be provided later on). I have used an array of words to get a random word to play with. But as a next step I want to use an XMLHttpRequest to get a random word from a separate website, I was wondering if someone could point me towards a tutorial or give me some information on how to start!
Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myWords = new Array("first", "hello", "goodbye", "random", "word", "last");
    var item = myWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * myWords.length)];
    var length = item.length;
    var guessedLetters = "";
    var error = 0;

    function partialWords(item, letters) {
        var returnLetter = "";
        for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            if (letters.indexOf(item[i]) !== -1) {
                returnLetter = returnLetter + item[i];
            } else {
                returnLetter = returnLetter + '_';
            }
        }
        return returnLetter;
    }

    function load() {
        var input = document.getElementById("hangmanID").value;
        var myWords2 = (item.indexOf(input) >= 0);

        if (myWords2 === false) {
            console.log("That letter is not in the word");
            document.getElementById("hangmanID").value = "";
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "That letter was wrong!";
            document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "";
            error++;

            if (error > 0) {
                document.getElementById('hangmanImg').innerHTML = "<img src='assets/" + error + ".png'>";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('hangmanImg').innerHTML = "No Errors yet!";
            }
        } else {
            console.log("That letter is correct");
            var string = item.indexOf(input, 0);
            console.log(string);
            document.getElementById("hangmanID").value = "";
            document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "That letter was right!";
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
        }
            guessedLetters = guessedLetters + input;
            document.getElementById('hangman').innerHTML = partialWords(item, guessedLetters);
            document.getElementById("lettersUsed").innerHTML = guessedLetters;
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
PLEASE NOTE THAT I AM ALLOWED TO USE JSONP

Comment: Suggestion: Use a library (jQuery)/framework (Bootstrap/Angular/..etc.) to do this, it's already been implemented hundreds of times.
But if this is a learning exercise, fine :P

Comment: @Populus I would love to as I like jQuery, however as I'm learning JavaScript as a module in University jQuery is out of the question

Comment: If the other website is in other domain, be aware of [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Also there are restrictions to using AJAX to fetch content from another website if it has a different domain (even subdomain). You will need to investigate on JSONP for that.

Comment: Tip for cross-domain AJAX: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Comment: In a comment to a deleted question you mentioned JSONP. Please specify if you're allowed to use JSONP in the question (the server is capable of responding with JSONP packets) since it's not directly possible to do this using XMLHttpRequest but it is simple using JSONP (note: JSONP does not use XMLHttpRequest but instead uses/abuses the `<script>` tag)

Comment: @Slebetman I have updated question, do you know how to do this? or at least are able to give me a starting point for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to same-origin-policy, XMLHttpRequest is not normally allowed to fetch data from other domains. There are work-arounds such as CORS or using a proxy on your domain or using an embedded flash or java applets.

However, JSONP is a different story. That's because JSONP does not technically return data. JSONP returns a javascript file. As such, getting data using JSONP simply requires you to add a script tag to your page:

```
<script src="http://other.server.com/path/to/jsonp/data"></script>
```

To do it programmatically:

```
var jsonp = document.createElement('script');
jsonp.src = "http://other.server.com/path/to/jsonp/data";
document.body.appendChild(jsonp);
```

The problem with this is that script tags don't return anything. To solve this, the JSONP protocol passes a function name to the server so that the server will wrap that function around the JSON data.

For example, if your regular JSON data looks like this:

```
{"result":"something"}
```

The JSONP equivalent would look something like this:

```
callback({"result":"something"})
```

So, to take the original example, our new code would now be:

```
function processResult (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}
var jsonp = document.createElement('script');
jsonp.src = "http://other.server.com/path/to/jsonp/data?jsonp=processResult";
document.body.appendChild(jsonp);
```

Notice how we're passing the name of the function to handle the return value in the query param of the URL.

Note that while in this example the parameter is "jsonp" the server may implement it using some other name. Another common one is "callback", as in `callback=processResult`. Read the API documentation of the server you're connecting to.

Comment: Ohh I see! thank you very much, that's actually helped me understand it a lot better

Comment: I have another question for you because I'm not back in University until after the weekend, do you have any example websites that display JSON data randomly? I can only access the original webpage from my University network. There probably isn't but just thought I'd ask. Thanks!

Comment: You can try USGS earthquake data: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week. It uses a hardcoded callback function called `eqfeed_callback` so you need to define that function in your code.

Comment: There's also freegeoip.net which lets you query user's location based on ip address. Supports jsonp with `callback` query param. See their website for the API documentation